# I cannot install OR run a live session of Ubuntu Gnome 15.10 either with a USB key or DVD

Tags: gnome, usb, dvd

I use Ubuntu Unity but recently wanted to look at other distros such as elementary and gnome. In all cases I could run a live session and/or install.

The exception is Ubuntu Gnome. My USB just can't boot. I know they get broken so I went out and bought a new one with the same result.

So I tried burning a DVD but I get a message saying the installer has met an unrecoverable error...

I threw the DVD away and went out and bought some new ones with the same result.

I tested the hash.

I then tried elementary and fedora 23 with NO problems.

Can anyone please make any suggestions (other than to stay with Unity)!

Thx

Comment: What was the exact error message?

Answer (score 1):

You could install gnome as a desktop environment within Ubuntu. You don't have to install elementary or gnome as a separate distro.

To install Gnome:

```
sudo apt-get install ubuntu-gnome-desktop
```

You can find out how to install the pantheon desktop [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/696650/install-pantheon-desktop-on-ubuntu-15-10).

To choose which environment you want to use, click:

[image]
<sub>(source: [howtogeek.com](https://cdn5.howtogeek.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/07/650x300xselect-desktop-environment-on-ubuntu-default-login-screen-or-display-manager.png.pagespeed.ic.DZBtUsQSlh.png))</sub>