# Install Elementary Pantheon desktop for Ubuntu 16.04?

Tags: 16.04, themes, elementary, pantheon

Is it possible to install the pantheon desktop environment on Ubuntu 16.04?

For many previous versions, it was only possibly by adding the unstable PPA, and installing from there, as explained [here](https://askubuntu.com/a/697459/146980).

Is this still the case or is there a stable build available?
I haven't tried since I don't want to break my system...

Comment: What about trying it in a VM?

Answer (score 2):

I have installed the pantheon desktop on Ubuntu 16.04. Yes it works. I have some troubles with the desktop background and my conkys. But I think it is possible to solve the problems.

this was my way:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:elementary-os/daily
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:elementary-os/os-patches
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:elementary-os/testing
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:mpstark/elementary-tweaks-daily

sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get dist-upgrade

sudo apt-get install elementary-theme elementary-icon-theme elementary-default-settings elementary-desktop
```

Comment: that's the same as the previous version of Ubuntu :(